# Do I have to find derivative gx and gy here in order to find the global maximum or just find the extreme points within the domain?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I tried to find gx and gy = 0 and solve for x and y but it seems like a difficult derivative to do, therefore I am wondering if I have to do that at all or maybe just plug in the domain into the function and find the extreme points

Comment: What was difficult about taking the partial derivative with respect to $x$ and $y$? Can you show us your work and we can see where you got stuck?

Comment: I derived gx and got $1+r^2 $= $\frac{-2r^2 cos^2 \theta}{1+ r^2}$ but dont know how to proceed from here and find values for 'r' or $\theta$ for that matter

Comment: Use $x$ and $y$ instead of polar coordinates. And it's easier to start with the equation $g_y=0$; that will give you information that you can then use in the equation $g_x=0$.

Comment: By the way, using images is discouraged. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Answer (score 0):

$g(r,\theta) = r \cos \theta \ln(1 + r^2)$ where $r \le 1$. Differentiating
\begin{align}
g_r & = \cos \theta \left[\ln (1 + r^2) + \frac{2r^2}{1 + r^2} \right] \\
g_\theta & = -r \sin \theta \ln(1 + r^2).
\end{align}
Note that for $r > 0$, $g_r$ and $g_\theta$ are not simultaneously $0$ (check!). The only critical point is $r = 0$ (can you figure out what type it is?)

Next you need to evaluate $g$ along the boundary as it could take its max and min there. Indeed it does when $\theta = 0, \pi$, respectively.